# SKEffectNode Performance Issue for CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") with shouldRasterize = true

Tags: ios, swift, performance, sprite-kit, skeffectnode

I am trying to add a glow to characters or objects in my game that cause damage.  I want a red glow for "bad" things in the game, i.e., spikes, guards, etc.  I am using the following code, but the performance is really bad even with rasterize set to true.  The performance drops pretty quickly from 60fps to ~30fps when I add the effects.  The glow effect needs to be on sprites of different shapes, ie. circles, triangles, rectangles, people, etc..  I am open to other approaches, although the code below gives me the exact visual effect I want.  If I can get the code to perform, I would like to put a green glow on "good" objects.

I have also reduced the amount of "bad" SKNodes by only adding nodes that are 1.5 scenes to the left and the right.  This change didn't seem to help.  The issue appears to be when I actually come to a particularly heavy population of SKNodes and SKNodes/SKSpriteNodes with the effect added.

```
glowAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "GlowTextures")

// create a glowing effect
func getGlow(imageName: String, imageSize: CGSize, glowColor: SKColor) -> SKEffectNode {
```

try

```
 let glow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageName)
```

or

```
let texture = glowAtlas.textureNamed(imageName)
let glow = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
```

...

```
 glow.size = imageSize
 glow.color = glowColor
 glow.colorBlendFactor = 1.0

 // Create an effects node with a gaussian blur filter
 let effectsNode = SKEffectNode()
 effectsNode.shouldRasterize = true
 effectsNode.shouldEnableEffects = true

 let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
 // Set the blur amount. Adjust this to achieve the desired effect
 let blurAmount = 5.0
 filter!.setValue(blurAmount, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

 effectsNode.filter = filter
 effectsNode.blendMode = .Alpha
 effectsNode.addChild(glow)

 return effectsNode
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on a device or on Simulator ? Also how many glow effects do you have on screen at the same time ? And what happens with glow effect when it finishes with glowing ? Do  you remove it or just fade it out?

Comment: I am running on both the simulator and an iPhone 5s.  I leave the effect on the entire time as it allows the user to see what is "bad".  On levels where I have just a few, a device FPS is 58 and where I have between 5 and 20 on the viewable screen but ~100 total in memory, 80-95 not displayed, the FPS is ~35.  The issue is about 2 times worse on the simulator, which I believe is common.

Comment: I can't test this by myself right now, but you can try two things : 1) Instead of using `imageNamed` method, try to create SKSpriteNode using the texture for each effect. Also put those textures into a texture atlas. 2) This would be a workaround, so if possible, use textures for glow effect. You will have a bunch of textures for this but it will be performant if you keep them in atlas. And yeah, Simulator uses software renderer, so its results are not realistic.

Comment: I have tried the recommendations to change from imageNamed to texture and attempted to use a textureAtlas.  Neither seems to have an effect on the FPS.  I even adjusted the code to only add the "bad" nodes and their SKEffectNodes +/- 1.5 scene sizes.  This change didn't appear to have any impact either.  The relative FPS appears to be game location positional.  There are places where only 4 bad objects are displayed and the FPS drops to 55, as I move the hero slightly left or right and "bad" objects move on/off the scene, FPS drops to 50 then back up to 55 as the hero character stops moving.

Comment: I did some additional testing and the above code actually performs fine.  My actual performance issue related to how many SKNodes were being managed to which I attached the SKEffectNode in combination with my update: function.  In the update: function I was enumerating over the nodes with the effects which actually caused the performance problem.  When I reduced the number of SKNodes with effects managed and removed the enumeration from the update: statement, the above code performed near 60fps on a device.